# SQL Query, INNER JOIN AND ROW OVER PARTITION, am I doing this right?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, window-functions

I have table that stores incoming emails, I use this table to then reply to the email and record in a seperate log table that I have replied to them.

I need to write some SQL that will do the following:

If the incoming email is new (not replied to), e.g. hasnt been put into the log table then I send email response A, I then need to check if an incoming email is new but this user has previously sent in an email, if so I send response B.

So far I have this...

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(FOLLOWUP.EmailId, 0) = 0 THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
     ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)
END AS FollowUp   
from INCOMINGEMAILS CE 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by EmailSenderId order by CreateDate desc) as rn
    FROM INCOMINGEMAILS 

) FOLLOWUP ON CE.EmailSenderId = FOLLOWUP.EmailSenderId AND FOLLOWUP.rn = 1 AND CE.EmailId <> FOLLOWUP.EmailId 
WHERE CE.EmailId NOT IN (
    SELECT EPL.EmailId  FROM LOG EPL 
    WHERE ISNULL(EPL.Processed, CAST(0 AS BIT)) = CAST(1 AS BIT)
)
AND ISNULL(CE.EmailSenderId, 0) <> 0
```

So basically what I am doing is first of all checking that the new incoming email is in fact new, e.g. has not been inserted into the log. If so I will send email repsonse A.

Then I check if the email response is new but the emailsender has previously sent in another email, I do this by doing the left join then doing a case statement to populate the 'followup' field.

If the field 'followup' is 1/true then I send email response B.

Can anyone see any flaws in what I am doing here, does this look like the right query to perform for my situation?

Any feedback greatly appreciated.

CREATE SCRIPTS

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INCOMINGEMAILS](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- PK, AUTO INCREMENT
    [EmailId] [int] NULL, -- UNIQUE EMAIL ID
    [EmailSenderId] [int] NULL, -- UNIQUE ID FOR USER/EMAIL SENDER
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [EmailContent] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL
}
```

Comment: can you please add ddls and insert script for tables and the expected output u need. Thanks

Comment: I have added inserts